# Do Git merges affect the "merged" branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

The company I work for has been trying out a Git workflow with three main branches (develop, beta, master) plus individual feature branches. This involves merging feature branches into 'develop' and 'beta' independently of one another, and then periodically merging 'beta' into 'master' for releases.

The problem: when we merge a feature branch to 'develop', it seems to affect the commit history for the feature branch, so when we try to merge that same branch into 'beta' it will also include all the commits from 'develop', which is not what we want.

Does anyone know what's going on here? Is it possible to merge a branch into two other branches without including any unwanted commits? What changes to our workflow could prevent this? I know there's no code sample or anything, but it's not really that type of question and I'm not sure how else to give more useful information.

Thank you!

Comment: No, merging does only affect one branch. I guess you're doing something wrong. But if the feature branch is based off of develop, obviously the feature branch contains all the commits of develop up to the commit on which the branching happened.

Comment: Where do the feature branches get branched from? master or develop?

Comment: try using the console command "git gui" to visualize your repository and post a screenshot of it? it will be a lot helpful.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The feature branches are created from 'develop' since they often need to share code and I can't get anybody to learn how to cherry pick. I imagine this is a large part of the problem.

Comment: @MladenB. I can't seem to find a useful area to screenshot. I am terrible at reading these version control visualizations.

Comment: @MladenB. Here's a screenshot taken with git extensions: https://a.pomf.cat/hjpjyv.PNG - looks much more complex than it should be, somehow. I don't know why 'beta' was merged into 'develop' at one point, that should never happen.

Answer (score 13):

The merge operation doesn't really affect *any* branch, in one fundamental sense.  (It does of course make a new commit, which affects that branch in the usual way.)  The trick with Git is to keep the following five simultaneous ideas in your head:

1. What matters in Git are commits, and their parent links.  Branch *names* are mostly just distractions (but see points 2 and 3).
2. A *branch name* is just the name for a particular commit, which we call the *tip commit* of that branch.
3. When making a new commit, Git writes the new commit with the current commit as its parent.<sup>1</sup>  If the new commit has multiple parents (see next point), the current commit becomes its *first* parent.  In any case Git then updates the branch-name to point to the new commit.  This is how branches "grow".
4. A *merge commit* is a commit with two (or more) parent commits.  This is "merge as a noun", as it were.
5. The act of *making* a merge—by which I mean a merge commit—involves doing the three-way-merge *action*, then making a new commit as usual, except that the new commit has two (or more) parents.  The "extra" parents are the merged-in commit(s).<sup>2</sup>

The merge action—"merge as a verb"—uses the history built up through the five points above.  Git finds three commits:

- The current commit, aka `HEAD`.  (This is easy.)
- The commit(s) to be merged: whatever ID(s) `git rev-parse` comes up with for the argument(s) you pass to `git merge`.  A branch name just finds the branch-tip commit.
- The *merge base*.  This is where the commit history comes in, and this is why you need to draw graph fragments.

The merge base of any two commits is loosely defined as "the (first) point where the graph comes back together":

```
...--o--*--o--o--o     <-- branch1
         \
          o--o--o--o   <-- branch2
```

The name `branch1` points to the tip (rightmost) commit on the top line.  The name `branch2` points to the tip commit on the bottom line.  The *merge base* of these two commits is the one marked `*`.<sup>3</sup>

To perform the merge action, Git then diffs (as in `git diff`) the merge base commit `*` against the two tips, giving two diffs.  Git then combines the diffs, taking just one copy of each change: if both you (on `branch1`) and they (on `branch2`) changed the word `color` to `colour` in `README`, Git just takes the change once.

The resulting *source*, as stored in the work-tree, becomes the tree for the merge commit.  Note that up until this point, it does not matter whether we are merging `branch2` into `branch1`, or `branch1` into `branch2`: we will get the same merge base, and have the same two tip commits, and hence get the same two diffs and combine those two diffs in the same way to arrive at the same work-tree.  But now we make the actual merge *commit*, with its two parents, and *now* it matters which branch we're on.  If we are on `branch1`, we make the new commit *on* `branch1`, and advance the name `branch1`:

```
...--o--o--o--o--o---M   <-- branch1
         \          /
          o--o--o--o     <-- branch2
```

The new merge commit has two parents: one is the old tip of `branch1` and the other is the tip of `branch2`.

Because we now have a new graph, a later `git merge` will find a new *merge base*.  Let's say that we make several more commits on both branches:

```
...--o--o--o--o--o---M--o--o     <-- branch1
         \          /
          o--o--o--*---o--o--o   <-- branch2
```

If we now ask to merge the two branches, Git first finds the base.  That's a commit that's on *both* branches, nearest to the two tips.  I've identified this commit as `*` again, and look where it is: it's the commit that used to be the tip of `branch2`, back when we did the merge.

Note that this is still the case regardless of which way we do the merge.

It is, however, critical that we make an actual merge commit.  If we use `git merge --squash`, which *does not* make a merge commit, we will *not* get this kind of graph.  It's also important that neither branch gets "rebased" after merging, since `git rebase` works by *copying* commits, and `git merge` works on the basis of commit identities and following parent pointers.  Any copies are different commits, so any old commits will not point into the new copied commits.  (It's OK to rebase commits *after* the merge point—to the right, in these drawings; what's not OK is copying commits that are to the left.)

If you do not prohibit `git merge` from doing a "fast forward" operation, it's also possible for `git merge` to skip making a merge commit, and instead just *move the branch label*.  In this case the two branch labels—the one you just moved, and the one you asked to merge—wind up pointing to *the same commit*.  Once this happens, there's no way to "untangle" the two branches except by moving the label back.  To prevent `git merge` from doing this fast-forward instead of actually merging, use `--no-ff`.

Here is an example of a fast-forward "merge" (in quotes because there is no actual merge).  We start, as usual, with diverged branches—but there are no commits on the *current* branch, `branch1`, that are not already *also* on the *other* branch, `branch2`:

```
...--o--*           <-- branch1
         \
          o--o--o   <-- branch2
```

If, while sitting on `branch1`, we run `git merge branch2`—note the lack of `--no-ff`—Git notices that no actual merging is required.  Instead, it does a label "fast forward" operation, sliding the name `branch1` forward until it meets the tip commit on `branch2`:

```
...--o--o
         \
          o--o--o   <-- branch1, branch2
```

This graph has nowhere to record any "separateness" between the two branches, so we might as well straighten out the kink:

```
...--o--o--o--o--o   <-- branch1, branch2
```

until we make new commits on `branch2`:

```
...--o--o--o--o--*     <-- branch1
                  \
                   o   <-- branch2
```

There's nothing *wrong* with this, but note how it is now impossible to tell that the three commits we "moved up" to the first row were merged.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is true for regular `git commit` and for `git merge`, but not for `git commit --amend`.  The "amend" variant of a commit makes a new commit as usual, but instead of setting the *current* commit as the new commit's parent, it sets the current commit's *parents* (as many of them as there are, which may even be no parents at all) as the new commit's parents.  The effect is to shove the current commit aside, making it *seem as though* the commit has changed, when in fact the old commit is still in the repository.

<sup>2</sup>The more-than-two-parents case is called an "octopus merge" and we can ignore it here.  (It does nothing you cannot do with repeated pairwise merges.)

<sup>3</sup>In complex graphs there may be more than one such "first point".  In this case, *all* lowest-common-ancestor nodes are merge bases, and for Git, the `-s strategy` merge strategy argument decides how to handle this case.  (Of course, there is also the `-s ours` strategy, which ignores all the other commits, and simply bypasses the three-way merge code entirely.  But I'm assuming normal merge here.)

Comment: After a day of searching, this explanation is by far the most straightforward explanation of merging.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there is a `pull` that was done from the feature branch. That is the one of the most common ways that commits from develop show up in your feature branch.

But as a general practice note the following steps are recommended,

1. While beginning work checkout a new feature branch based of off
   develop.
2. Finish the work and commit all of it on the feature branch.
3. Do a `git pull --rebase origin develop` to make sure that the
   feature  branch is ready for merge.
4. Checkout the develop branch.
5. Do a `git pull --rebase origin develop` and make sure your local
   develop is updated.
6. Do a `git merge <feature branch name>`

That should be a foolproof way of doing it.

Comment: It's not the *only* way, since branch names are just pointers to commits. Any operation that moves the name-labels around could do that. However, `git pull` runs `git merge`, unless you tell it to run `git rebase` instead, and of course `git merge` will make a merge commit—or, worse for this particular case, do a fast-forward label-move, if possible and permitted.

Comment: Agree. Actually i meant one of the most common ways. +1

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm not going to be able to get anyone on my team to use the command line for this, so is there any way to replicate these steps using the Github app + website?

These are basically the steps we already follow:

1. Make a new feature branch off of develop
2. Commit all work on the feature branch
3. Merge the feature branch to develop using the github website

Simplified, but basically the same from what I can tell. Where are we going wrong?

Comment: I do not recommend using the github web site for merging. It messes up history. Also you may use tortoise git to do a pull rebase from the feature branch against the develop branch.